# Authentication using SOAP header in web service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to implement authentication using `SOAP` for a webservice, but it seems that the element, sent in header is always `null`.

Here is my `[WebMethod]`:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "TestWService")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
public AuthenticateUser User;
[WebMethod]
[SoapHeader("User")]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml)]
public void AllCountriesInfo()
{
 Context.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(User));
 if (User != null)
 {
  if (User.IsValid())
  { 
   Context.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject("User is authenticated"));
  }
 }
Context.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject("User Data is missing"));
}
}
```

`AuthenticateUser` class:

```
public class AuthenticateUser : System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeader
{
 public string UserName { get; set; }
 public string Password { get; set; }

 public bool IsValid()
 {
  AccountMembershipService MembershipService = new AccountMembershipService();
  return MembershipService.ValidateUser(UserName, Password);
 }
}
```

And the `request`:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <AuthenticateUser xmlns="TestWService">
      <UserName>testadmin</UserName>
      <Password>pass</Password>
    </AuthenticateUser>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <AllCountriesInfo xmlns="TestWService" />
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Can anyone point me in the direction of the error I am doing?

Comment: @bommelding it is there, I have not included in the question. But now it's there.

Comment: You need to specify a return type on the `AllCountriesInfo` method. It currently returns `void`.